# CORS Origin Request not allowed React Express

Tags: reactjs, http, cors

I am using react & express for a simple form 
and i get this when i post my react form to express server

```js
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**And this is what i tried in my express server.js** :

```js
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true
  })
);
```

and in my middlevvare

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:9000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
});
```

i tried post req by axios :

```
axios
 .post("http://localhost:4000/api/user", data)
 .then(() => console.log("Tadaaa"))
 .catch(err => {
   console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: `credential: true` is this required?

Comment: i don't know, but too many tutorials recommended it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS requests that has `credentials: true` will not work with `origin: "*"`. If you wish to include credentials, then you need to specify your origin, which also do not work with localhost. Therefore I would recommend not including credentials unless your application is hosted online.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) for more information about CORS and how it works.

Comment: i tried this: `app.use(cors({ origin: "*" }));` and still got same err :(

Comment: You could try this: 
`  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:[your port]');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');`

I have experienced issues in some browser, in particular Chrome, when using localhost. But you could give it a try. 
Sorry for the format, can't seem to make a code-block in comments.

Comment: still not fixed :((

Comment: Weird, is the error still the same?

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

 next();
}

Try using this middleware function instead of app.use(cors), that is the function I have set up for my project, to make it work with a localhost server and client.

Comment: still the same =(((

Comment: can vve talk in chat?

Comment: Sorry for late response, we can talk in chat yes.

Comment: np, so where we can  talk?

Answer (score -1):

Does the api user endpoint exist? Otherwise try passing the cors middleware without the extra options.

Comment: yes, i did `` app.use(cors()); `` and i got error above + `` Error: Network Error ``

Comment: The end point exists right? And also the server is running? Sometimes you can get that error if the endpoint doesn’t exist

Comment: yes, server is running on port 4000, and react on 9000, all get requests work perfectly

Comment: You might need to post more code since I’m not sure why you would get that error from the code I’ve seen.

Answer (score -1):

The Err fixed , by passing the `app.use(cors());` before routes